# Who falls off cliff and is killed by the wights?

Tags: character, game-of-thrones

In *Game of Thrones*, Season 7 Episode 6, "Beyond the Wall", one person is seen fighting wights and then falls into the crowd of wights.

See at 4:05  in

Comment: Ranger #3... he was a good lad...

Comment: He is seen fighting wights. Also, for a fraction of second, Jon appears trying to hold him to prevent him from falling. In short, he should be one of the five good guys remaining ?

Comment: There was more than "The Seven" that went beyond the wall. We see them either leading out front as scouts, or in the rear dragging sleds. The total party was at least 10 IIRC, so that gives us 3 unnamed extras to have die.

Comment: Yes...I missed that. I went back to the beginning and could count total 13. Thanks

Comment: The initial group going beyond the wall. Clipped from video.
[One can count many here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yw7uB.jpg)

Comment: Mr. Ran 'Dom' Plebb

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The part [does not seem to be credited](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt5775864/fullcredits?ref_=tt_cl_sm#cast). The best-case scenario is the credit for "[Wildling](http://www.imdb.com/character/ch0552992/?ref_=ttfc_fc_cl_t17)".

These types of characters are commonly referred as ["Red-shirts"](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/73107/is-there-a-specific-name-for-a-character-that-is-a-sacrificial-example/73109#73109). They are a part of the party of heroes, and exist only to die to show the audience that the situation is indeed dire.

Comment: I'm going to have to watch that episode again & count the red shirts - I'm sure they keep multiplying. Every time another got killed off I was thinking "How many were there to start with & how many are left now?"

Comment: @Tetsujin LOL yeah i know. I think there was at least 3. One in front (got killed by the bear) and two pulling sleds in the rear.

Comment: I vaguely remember one of the early Star Trek PC adventure games that literally did this; if you were getting yourself in too dangerous of a situation one of your Red-shirts would die as a warning to back off a bit.

Comment: @Tetsujin There are many scenes where there were 10, and then there are randomly 13. and then 10 again, and then someone dies but there are 13 in the next shot. Probably an artifact of shooting scenes, and then patching them together.

Comment: "Luckily" all red-shirts die so they don't have extra useless weight on the dragon...

Comment: @DariM - That's why they employ people to do continuity, so stuff like that doesn't happen. I bets heads will roll somewhere for that. I'm trying to imagine the setup, just before roll... "Final checks.." "Oh yeah, how many red shirts should be left by now?" "Not a clue, let's just go" "Did we catalogue these setups?" "Ermmm, we got to Z, then Bill dropped his pen in the snow" ... "Ah... we'll fix it in the edit"...

Comment: @Tetsujin: When the episode opened with a shot of the traveling party, that is the first thing I tried to keep track of (especially since characters are hard to distinguish in the heat of battle, a lot of long hair and beards). We have 7 major characters (Jon, Beric, Thoros, Jorah, Thormund, Sandor, Gendry), and I counted 10-14 (spitball) in the wide shot. Maybe not all redshirts have been shown in every scene, but the initial count seems to match up with about how many have died.

Comment: @Flater I'm sure the start and end counts will match up. After all, they probably wouldn't cast extras if they didn't have a redshirt death for them. The continuity in the middle is where it got jarring for me. But that kinda thing seems endemic of late, and there are more important peeves, e.g. Tormund Giantsbane making a big deal about Mance Rayder not KNEELING? What?

Comment: @DariM: Thormund's understanding of the feudal system may have changed, after he sees the lords of the North bend the knee to Jon but it being a _formality_ rather than an actual change in their freedom. If Thormund sees living south of the Wall as a good thing (likely, with the Walker threat), then it makes sense that he would've preferred Mance to bend the knee since it is nothing more than a tokenistic gesture. Furthermore, Thormund is also not excessively intelligent, so he may be projecting his current feelings on his memories of the past (not everyone is factually correct all the time)

Comment: @DariM: Thormund may simply have come to understand that Mance's refusal to bend the knee was nothing more but Mance's pride getting in the way (Jon is being told the same thing about not bending the knee to Dany), which got some of the wildlings killed in ensuing battles between them and the Watch. I'm not saying that it can't be a case of bad writing, but a shift in character or a change of opinion is not automatically indicative of bad writing. Characters evolve, and we haven't seen much of Thormund lately so it could've happened off-screen.